Cannot edit vertexes of a newly added element in a PostgreSQL view in QGIS
I usually work in QGIS with many views created in PostgreSQL that I edit directly through triggers. Since I've started working this way I found out a problem: Every time I insert a new feature I cannot edit its vertexes or its shape just right after saving. The only way to do that is by opening the attribute table of the layer and refreshing the data. With time I developed a way to draw that minimize the impact of the problem, but it's something that I really cannot digest. From what I can see it's definitely something related to the view in the project because the database is correctly updated and if I work directly with table the problem doesn't persist.
I actually tried many roads working on the database (refreshing indexes, etc) and on the project itself using Python, but I've not even been able to set up a routine that refresh the attribute table automatically.
I remember reading something on the forum but I cannot find that anymore. Has someone ever experienced something like that and find a way through?

Do you have  "Cache Database Connections" disabled (Settings > Options > Data Sources) ?
